# Which taskschd.msc is it?

Tags: windows

I just ran a search of the whole hard drive and found that there were 8 taskschd.msc [HERE](http://goo.gl/wjNQxV)

My question is which taskschd.msc is the one currently in use??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one in system32. You have three variants there: Native x64, native x86 and x86 on x64.

Those in WinSxS are just hardlinks to the very same files.

Answer (score 0):

My work proxy server blocks your image host because it's most commonly used for pornography, so I would suggest using imgur instead.

On to the question at hand.

In Task Manager, go to View, Select Columns. Turn on Command Line. Then find your task, and scroll over to that column. The answer should be right there.

Comment: Have changed the link to imgur